# Wordpress - filter video embed code

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, how do you filter a textarea that saves a vimeo embed code in theme admin? Using sanitize_text_field will make the code unusable when saving into db via update_post_meta.

```
    $postmeta = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['embed_video']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'embed_video',$postmeta );
```

Comment: Not sure if it fits your application, but there's a great plugin called `[iframe]` that allows video embed code within the WYSIWYG page/post editor: http://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/

Answer (score 0):

I often approach wordpress video embeds from the other angle, creating the embed code in the template, for example rather than have someone embed a video like this:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/69277800?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;badge=0" width="577" height="325" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

I'd have them just insert the id, in this case 69277800. Then I'd put in my template

```
<?php if(!empty($video_id)):?>
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $video_id;?>?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;badge=0" width="577" height="325" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: yes but in this case i need to put several extra options- like - is vimeo or youtube / height, width ,etc... I was looking for a way to validate this Post in one single move.

Comment: You could use something like http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php - Sorry I know my answers aren't ideal, just trying to help out.  Also, I'd recommend wordpress.stackexchange for questions like these

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you save the video's URL in a text input (continue using `sanitize_text_field()`) and then output the embed code using WordPress's [`wp_get_oembed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get) function. This will work on a variety of allowed providers, such as Youtube and Vimeo. This method is safer as long as you are using allowed providers and I believe it is possible to add providers to the whitelist in the off-chance you are using someone pretty obscure.

```
$input = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_input', true );
echo wp_oembed_get( $input );
```

Additionally, you can whitelist the `iframe` and sanitize the textarea using `wp_kses()` as shown in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22986053/383847).