# Wordpress Custom Meta Box Display HTML CODE correctly

Tags: wordpress

so basically I took the code that is described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Procedural

and it works just fine.
Then I went over to my content.php (single, page) and wrote the following:
`<?php $fea_vid= get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true); ?>`

and to print it:

`<?php echo $fea_vid; ?>`

Now it works just fine if I typ text in BUT and here is my problem:

I want that the user is able to but a video embed code in the custom meta box input and then I want that code to display the video on the page.
It works just fine if you use custom fields... but I want a special box for it, cause I want it to be obvious that the code just goes there. Make it more user friendly...

So yeah... How do I stop wordpress from stripping all html code off the meta box entry and how to I make it display the video correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: The example block of code you linked to uses `sanitize_text_field()` which will pretty much strip everything from the field. What does your embed code look like? Can you grab the URL or ID and generate the embed code yourself? [See this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44807/sanitize-vimeo-embed-code)

Comment: I want the embed code to be just anything the user wants to put there: YouTube, Vimeo, Dailymotion etc. will try to see about the `sanitize_text_field()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 ways to attack this. First we can switch to a text area input and then sanitize it differently so as to allow iframes (which are not usually allowed by WordPress). I don't love this method as technically you can then save iframes with unknown sources, but it does work.

The second method is to continue using a text input and then output the embed code using WordPress's [`wp_get_oembed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get) function. This will work on a variety of allowed providers, such as Youtube and Vimeo. This method is safer as long as you are using allowed providers and I believe it is possible to add providers to the whitelist in the off-chance you are using someone pretty obscure.

I will include both in my modified metabox code:

```
/**
 * Prints the box content.
 * 
 * @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
 */
function myplugin_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'myplugin_meta_box', 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' );

    /*
     * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
     * from the database and use the value for the form.
     */
    $input = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_input', true );
    $textarea = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_textarea', true );

    echo '<label for="myplugin_new_textarea">';
    _e( 'Description for this textarea', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<textarea id="myplugin_new_textarea" name="myplugin_new_text_area">' . esc_html( $textarea ) . '</textarea>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<label for="myplugin_new_input">';
    _e( 'Description for this input', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input id="my_plugin_new_input" type="text" name="myplugin_new_text_input" value="' . esc_url( $input ) . '" size="25" />';

}
```

The save routine is where things are a little different from the codex example. You'll see that for the text input I am still using `sanitize_text_field()` but for the text area I am adding an `iframe` to the whitelist of allowed tags and running the content through [`wp_kses()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses). Otto wrote a great post on the various [kses functions](http://ottopress.com/2010/wp-quickie-kses/) that explains it better than I could. I went with `wp_kses()` because it allowed me to whitelist the `iframe` only in this instance. If you search around I am sure you can discover how to whitelist an iframe for the post content as well, if you wanted.

```
/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
 */
function myplugin_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    /*
     * We need to verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because the save_post action can be triggered at other times.
     */

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'], 'myplugin_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    } else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /* OK, its safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Save the textarea 
    if ( isset( $_POST['myplugin_new_text_area'] ) ) {

        // WP's default allowed tags
        global $allowedtags;

        // allow iframe only in this instance
        $iframe = array( 'iframe' => array(
                            'src' => array (),
                            'width' => array (),
                            'height' => array (),
                            'frameborder' => array(),
                            'allowFullScreen' => array() // add any other attributes you wish to allow
                             ) );

        $allowed_html = array_merge( $allowedtags, $iframe );

        // Sanitize user input.
        $my_data = wp_kses( $_POST['myplugin_new_text_area'], $allowed_html );

        //$my_data = $_POST['myplugin_new_text_area'];

        // Update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_textarea', $my_data );
    }

    // save the text input
    if ( isset( $_POST['myplugin_new_text_input'] ) ) {
        // Sanitize user input.
        $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['myplugin_new_text_input'] );
        // Update the meta field in the database.
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_input', $my_data );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data' );
```

Now finally for displaying the content on the front end. You should be able to straight-out echo the contents of the text area. And if you run the text input through `wp_oembed_get()` you should see pretty much the same thing:

```
$input = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_input', true );
echo wp_oembed_get( $input );

$textarea = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_textarea', true );
echo $textarea;
```

Comment: This works perfectly.... in the end I did go for the `$textarea` it's saver in the scene that all video embeds and other code is allowed... so people can do what ever they want with the field - what in the end of the day is what I want it to be. Thanks a LOT!

Comment: Cool. I probably would've gone gone with oembed. Well, next time I will use oembed because I just worked on a site and went the textarea route. I'm not sure if the `<embed>` tag is already allowed, but if not you can always add it to the whitelist of tags.

Comment: @helgatheviking, may I ask you to have a look at a wordpress custom field related question here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782429/wordpress-make-custom-field-values-clickable-to-retrive-them-later ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed If you wish to request my specific assistance you should consider hiring me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the meta box to a `textarea`

place this line instead of the `input type text`

```
 echo '<textarea id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" cols="60" rows="4">. esc_attr( $value ) . </textarea>';
```

then it should echo out correctly

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, even with deleting the `sanitize_text_field()` code line it keeps on stripping all html code when saving :/ ... also your line of code doesn't display the `$value` it only prints `. esc_attr( $value ) .`